# Why can't I call the C++ explicit specialization version of following code？

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-specialization

Introduction：I want the explicit sepiaclization to show the longest string, I thought it be "Carmelo Anthony", but the result is "Jordan". I know the general template version is used instead of the explicit one. So it just compare the point's value(address value),right ? But How could I see the "Carmelo Anthony"? Thank you for answering my first post !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>     //for strlen()

template <class T>     //general template
T maxn (T arr[], int n);
template <> char * maxn<char *>(char * arr[], int n);    //explicit specialization

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int intArr[6] = {1, 2, 34, 6, 9, 10};
    double douArr[4] = {2.34, 90.6, -83.872, -0.23};
    const char * arr[5] = 
    {
        "Hello World",
        "Kobe Bryant",
        "Lebron James",
        "Carmelo Anthony",
        "Jordan"            
    };
    std::cout << maxn (intArr, 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << maxn (douArr, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << maxn (arr, 5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <class T>
T maxn (T arr[], int n)
{
    T maxValue =  arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        maxValue = maxValue > arr[i] ? maxValue:arr[i];
    }
    return maxValue;
}

template <> char * maxn<char *>(char * arr[], int n)
{
    char * p= arr[0];   //pointer p points to the present longest string
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        p = strlen (arr[i]) > strlen (p) ? arr[i] : p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Works if you specify `const char*` instead of `char *`.  See here: http://ideone.com/ZmAp6D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition to the previous answer, you could specialize both `const char *` and `char *` by supplying a simple helper function that both versions will call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>     //for strlen()

template <class T>     //general template
T maxn(T arr[], int n);
template <> const char * maxn<const char *>(const char * arr[], int n);    //explicit specialization
template <> char * maxn<char *>(char * arr[], int n);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int intArr[6] = { 1, 2, 34, 6, 9, 10 };
    double douArr[4] = { 2.34, 90.6, -83.872, -0.23 };
    const char * arr[5] =
    {
        "Hello World",
        "Kobe Bryant",
        "Lebron James",
        "Carmelo Anthony",
        "Jordan"
    };

    char * arr2[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        arr2[i] = new char[strlen(arr[i]) + 1];
        strcpy(arr2[i], arr[i]);
    }

    std::cout << maxn(intArr, 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << maxn(douArr, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << maxn(arr, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << maxn(arr2, 5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <class T>
T maxn(T arr[], int n)
{
    T maxValue = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        maxValue = maxValue > arr[i] ? maxValue : arr[i];
    }
    return maxValue;
}

template<typename T> 
T* charHelper(T *arr[], int n)
{
    T* p = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        p = strlen(arr[i]) > strlen(p) ? arr[i] : p;
    }
    return p;
}

template <> char * maxn<char *>(char * arr[], int n)
{ return charHelper<char>(arr, n); }

template <> const char * maxn<const char *>(const char * arr[], int n)
{ return charHelper<const char>(arr, n); }
```

Output:

```
34
90.6
Carmelo Anthony
Carmelo Anthony
```

Disregard the obvious memory leak in the `main` function for now.

Note that for the `arr` version, the `const char*` specialization is called, while for the `arr2` version, the `char *` version is called.

Comment: OK ! I was wondering the memory leak when reading your code. Thank you,again.

Comment: @Mayboy You actually _don't_ need to specialize both `const char *` and `char *`. You can pass a (non-`const`) `char *` argument to a function taking `const char *` parameter. The `const` when present in the parameter list basically says "I promise not to change this data", and it doesn't matter if the argument was mutable or not to begin with.

Comment: @SchighSchagh  Yes, you are right. I was also aware of that yesterday,                                                                      but forgot to update it. template :                                                                                                 template<typename T> 
T* maxn(T *arr[], int n)
{
    T* p = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        p = strlen(arr[i]) > strlen(p) ? arr[i] : p;
    }
    return p;
}                                                                                     So, no need to specialize both const char * and char *, right ?

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulMcKenzie suggests, the problem is the missing `const`. To be a little more detailed, your template specialization is for arrays of pointers to non-`const` (ie, mutable) `char`. This tells the compiler that you might change the strings that are being passed in. However, you pass in an array of `const char *`, ie *immutable* strings. The compiler won't let you call a function that might mutate the data on `const` data, therefore it will not use your specialization unless you add `const`.